# multiple condition in single linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, optimization

I am iteration through the control which is having multiple rows and each row having a tag and just implemented the following linq. Can i optimize the following queries into single one?

```
 Dim xCheckTag As String = If((From xTag As Row In Sheet1.Rows Where xTag.Tag = "FtpHeader").ToArray.Length > 0, "FtpHeader", _
                            If((From xTag As Row In Sheet1.Rows Where xTag.Tag = "MailHeader").ToArray.Length > 0, "MailHeader", _
                            If((From xTag As Row In Sheet1.Rows Where xTag.Tag = "GoogleHeader").ToArray.Length > 0, "GoogleHeader", _
                            If((From xTag As Row In Sheet1.Rows Where xTag.Tag = "NetworkHeader").ToArray.Length > 0, "NetworkHeader", String.Empty))))
```

Comment: I would be more than happy to help but I do only C#. Can you take a C# answer and use your VB knowledge to translate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FirstOrDefault` as *Dominic* suggested, but it would return `null` instead of `String.Empty` if non of items matched. I would use `DefaultIfEmpty` to return proper default value:

```
Dim tags = {"FtpHeader","MailHeader","GoogleHeader","NetworkHeader"}
Dim xCheckTag = tags.Where(Function(tag) Sheet1.Rows.Cast(Of Row)().Any(Function(xTag) xTag.Tag = tag)) _
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty) _
                    .First()
```

Comment: sheet1.rows does't have any

Answer (score 0):

Using `FirstOrDefault` in combination with `Any`:

```
Dim tags = {"FtpHeader","MailHeader","GoogleHeader","NetworkHeader"}
Dim xCheckTag = If(tags.FirstOrDefault(Function(tag) Sheet1.Rows.OfType(Of Row).Any(Function(xTag) xTag.Tag = tag)), String.Empty)
```

Comment: sheet1.rows does't have any